# Combine two fields from different documents in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have these documents in a collection :

```
   {topic : "a",
    messages : [ObjectId("21312321321323"),ObjectId("34535345353"),...]
   },
   {topic : "b,
    messages : [ObjectId("1233232323232"),ObjectId("6556565656565"),...]
   }
```

Is there a posibility to get a result with the combination of messages fields ? I like to get this for example :

```
     {[
       ObjectId(""),ObjectId(""),ObjectId(""),ObjectId("")
     ]}
```

I thought that this was possible with MapReduce but in my case the documents doesn't have anything in common. Right now I'm doing this in the backend using javascript and loops, but i think that this isn't the best option. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/) operator in the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/). To use the Aggregation Framework you will want to be sure you're running on MongoDB 2.2 or newer, of course.

If used with [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) you will get all the lists of messages concatenated together.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({ $group: { messages: { $push: '$messages' } } });
```

If used with [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) you will get only the distinct values.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({ $group: { messages: { $addToSet: '$messages' } } });
```

And if you want to filter down the candidate documents first, you can use [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/).

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { $match: { topic: { $in: [ 'a', 'b' ] } } },
    { $group: { matches: { $sum: 1 }, messages: { $push: '$messages' } } }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the aggregation framework.

However, if you're planning on having a large number of results (beyond just a "lightweight" result),  a result document exceeding 16MB in size, or using excessive system memory, you'll need to just loop through the objects in the collection and concatenate the results manually (as you suggest you might be doing now) or risk mongodb throwing an exception.

Aggregation limits may be found at the bottom of this page:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Given the limitations, you may want to just use [find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) with a projection to return just `messages`.

(And with anything like this, I'd strongly recommend you do some performance benchmarks to compare options with your data on your servers as the "Internet" would suggest right now that some people have found the Aggregation support to be slower than other techniques).

Comment: Yes, there are limitations to the Aggregation Framework. The right solution, especially at scale, requires balancing trade-offs. Even if you don't hit the framework limitations it may be more scalable to do the in-memory merging of lists in your client rather than the database server.